# Failed to start cloud-era manager agent

Tags: cloudera-manager

Hi I am installing a 6 node cluster using cloud era manager 4.6 I am unable to add hosts to the cluster .I am running a Cloud-era manager server from a system with ip 192.168.x.x I would like to add this node to my cluster .But When i was trying i am getting a error message  like 
"Failed to start cloud-era manager agent"
and the log message is as below

```
/****************^****************************************************\

    BEGIN /sbin/service cloudera-scm-agent status | grep running
    END (1)
    BEGIN /sbin/service cloudera-scm-agent start
    /etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-agent: line 115: 
    /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.out: No such file or directory
    Starting cloudera-scm-agent: /etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-agent: line 118: /var/log
       /cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.out: No such file or directory

     [60G[[0;31mFAILED[0;39m]
     END (1)
     agent logs:
     BEGIN tail -n 50 /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.out | sed 's/^/>>/' 
      tail: cannot open `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.out' for  

     readingtail: cannot open `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.out' for 
     reading: No such file or directory

     : No such file or directory
     END (0)
     BEGIN tail -n 50 /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.log | sed 's/^/>>/'
     tail: cannot open `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.log' for

       reading:     No such file or directory
       tail: cannot open `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.log' 
       for    reading:    
      No such file or directory
      END (0)
      end of agent logs.
      scm agent could not be started, giving up
      waiting for rollback request 

      *****************************************************************************
      my network configuration files are as below 

      ********resolve.conf*************************
      www.domain.com
      nameserver 192.168.1.254
      localhost 127.0.0.1
      ***********/etc/sysconfig/network***********
      NETWORKING=yes
      HOSTNAME=192.1.1.1
      GATEWAY=192.168.1.254(not sure if i need to certainly  specify ..)
      ******************/etc/hosts******
      192.168.1.1 www.node1.com  host name
      ***************************

  I am stuck here for days and ran around network configuration files  any 
  suggestions    could be greatly appreciated thanks a lot
```

I just need to make sure Cloudera-manager agent is running on each node and then deploy the cluster or register the node.

There were some errors in the network configuration files ,which I have modified .and also

I could rectify this problem by making sure that the cloud era-manager agent is running on the node.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to make sure Cloudera-manager agent is running on each node and then deploy the cluster or register the node.

There were some errors in the network configuration files ,which I have modified .and also

I could rectify this problem by making sure that the cloud era-manager agent is running on the node.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would follow up on this part of the error:
"cannot open `/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent//cloudera-scm-agent.out' for 
 reading: No such file or directory"

Ensure that the directory exists, and that permissions are correct. The failure centers on the lack of that file.

Also check your configuration file (found in /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini ).  log_file=/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.log is the default location.

There are other gotchas like clock skew (i.e. different times on the different boxes) or have mismatched versions/rpms installed, but in this case your first stop is to see why nothing is being written to /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/cloudera-scm-agent.log